# Tesseract error: count > 0:Error:Assert failed:in file serialis.cpp, line 115

Tags: ubuntu, tesseract, leptonica

All,

I successfully installed tesseract 4.0.0-beta and leptonica-1.75.3. But when I try to test the installation by test their example image,

```
tesseract /home/tairen/tesseract-ocr/testing/eurotext.tif stdout
```

I got the error as:

```
count > 0:Error:Assert failed:in file serialis.cpp, line 115
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I do not know why is like that.
My OS is Ubuntu 16.04, the detailed tesseract version is:

```
tesseract --version
tesseract 4.0.0-beta.1-311-g83ae
leptonica-1.75.3
 libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 1.4.2) : libpng 1.2.54 : libtiff 4.0.6 : zlib 1.2.8
 Found AVX2
 Found AVX
 Found SSE
```

Please let me know if you have any hints.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

please download latest version, this error is caused by `ASSERT_HOST(count > 0);`in serialis.cpp. This bug had been repaired.